# Compute mip level selection from texcoord varying

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl

Marking as OpenGL even those the example in the question is WebGL because OpenGL domain experts should be able to answer this question. There's an OpenGL repo [here](https://github.com/greggman/macos-opengl-experiments/blob/main/macos-opengl-miplevel-calc/examples/example_apple_opengl2/main.mm)

I'm trying to compute texture mip levels the same way samplers do it based on texture coordinate derivatives.

I see lots of answers here and elsewhere. For example

- [How to access automatic mipmap level in GLSL fragment shader texture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388346/how-to-access-automatic-mipmap-level-in-glsl-fragment-shader-texture)
- [Derivation of OpenGL's mipmap level computation?](https://www.reddit.com/r/opengl/comments/3cdg5r/derivation_of_opengls_mipmap_level_computation/)
- [Mipmap level calculation using dFdx/dFdy](https://community.khronos.org/t/mipmap-level-calculation-using-dfdx-dfdy/67480)

All 3 of those say the calculation is

```
   vec2  dx_vtc        = dFdx(texture_coordinate);
   vec2  dy_vtc        = dFdy(texture_coordinate);
   float delta_max_sqr = max(dot(dx_vtc, dx_vtc), dot(dy_vtc, dy_vtc));

   mip_level = 0.5 * log2(delta_max_sqr);
```

Given that, I wrote a test. In the test I have 2 shaders.

- The first shader draws a quad using texture coordinates and sampling a texture. The texture has 7 mip levels, each level is a different solid color. As I increase the range of the texture coordinates I should see different mips get selected (using NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST). This works!
- The second shader draws a quad by computing the mip level using the formula above and then using that mip level to select a color from a table, the colors in the table match the colors in the texture. This does not work. All I ever see is red (the first color).

Here's the second shader

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

in vec2 v_texCoord;

out vec4 outColor;

const vec4 colors[8] = vec4[8](
  vec4(  1,   0,   0, 1), // 0: red
  vec4(  1,   1,   0, 1), // 1: yellow
  vec4(  0,   1,   0, 1), // 2: green
  vec4(  0,   1,   1, 1), // 3: cyan
  vec4(  0,   0,   1, 1), // 4: blue
  vec4(  1,   0,   1, 1), // 5: magenta
  vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1), // 6: gray
  vec4(  1,   1,   1, 1));// 7: white

void main() {
  vec2 dx = dFdx(v_texCoord);
  vec2 dy = dFdy(v_texCoord);
  float deltaMaxSq = max(dot(dx, dx), dot(dy, dy));
  float mipLevel = 0.5 * log2(deltaMaxSq);
  
  outColor = colors[int(mipLevel)];
}
```

Maybe I just have a typo but I've tried various ways of debugging

- I tried visualizing the texture coordinates in the second shader. They are clearly correct
- I tried making sure indexing the colors works. That works.
- I tried visualizing the mip level by writing `mipLevel / 7.0` from the shader, so as the mip level goes to 7 the quad should get brighter. This does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  height: 100%;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<script type="module">
import * as twgl from 'https://twgljs.org/dist/5.x/twgl-full.module.js';

const vs = `#version 300 es
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
uniform mat3 u_texMat;

out vec2 v_texCoord;

const vec2 position[6] = vec2[6](
  vec2(0, 0),
  vec2(1, 0),
  vec2(0, 1),
  vec2(0, 1),
  vec2(1, 0),
  vec2(1, 1));

void main() {
  vec2 p = position[gl_VertexID];
  v_texCoord = (u_texMat * vec3(p, 1)).xy;
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * vec4(p, 0, 1);
}
`;
const fsTex = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;

in vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_tex;

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  outColor = texture(u_tex, v_texCoord);
}
`;
const fsMipLevel = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;

in vec2 v_texCoord;

out vec4 outColor;

const vec4 colors[8] = vec4[8](
  vec4(  1,   0,   0, 1), // 0: red
  vec4(  1,   1,   0, 1), // 1: yellow
  vec4(  0,   1,   0, 1), // 2: green
  vec4(  0,   1,   1, 1), // 3: cyan
  vec4(  0,   0,   1, 1), // 4: blue
  vec4(  1,   0,   1, 1), // 5: magenta
  vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1), // 6: gray
  vec4(  1,   1,   1, 1));// 7: white

void main() {
  vec2 dx = dFdx(v_texCoord);
  vec2 dy = dFdy(v_texCoord);
  float deltaMaxSq = max(dot(dx, dx), dot(dy, dy));
  float mipLevel = 0.5 * log2(deltaMaxSq);
  
  // mipLevel = mod(gl_FragCoord.x / 16.0, 8.0);  // comment in to test we can use the colors

  outColor = colors[int(mipLevel)];

  // outColor = vec4(mipLevel / 7.0, 0, 0, 1);  // comment in to visualize another way
  // outColor = vec4(fract(v_texCoord), 0, 1);  // comment in to visualize texcoord
}
`;

const colors = [
  '#F00',
  '#FF0',
  '#0F0',
  '#0FF',
  '#00F',
  '#F0F',
  '#888',
  '#FFF',
];


function createMips(colors) {
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  const numMips = colors.length;
  return colors.map((color, i) => {
    const size = 2 ** (numMips - i - 1);
    ctx.canvas.width = size;
    ctx.canvas.height = size;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, size, size);
  });
}

function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl2");
  if (!gl) {
    alert("Sorry, this example requires WebGL 2.0");  // eslint-disable-line
    return;
  }

  const texProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fsTex]);
  const mipProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fsMipLevel]);

  const texImage = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texImage);
  const data = createMips(colors);
  data.forEach(({width, height, data}, level) => {
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, gl.RGBA8, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
  });
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

  const lerp = (a, b, t) => a + (b - a) * t;

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    const uniforms = {};

    const s = lerp(1, 128, Math.sin(time) * 0.5 + 0.5);
    uniforms.u_texMat = [
      s, 0, 0,
      0, s, 0,
      0, 0, 1,
    ];
    uniforms.u_worldViewProjection = m4.translation([-1.01, -0.5, 0]);

    gl.useProgram(texProgramInfo.program);
    twgl.setUniforms(texProgramInfo, uniforms);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    uniforms.u_worldViewProjection = m4.translation([0.01, -0.5, 0]);

    gl.useProgram(mipProgramInfo.program);
    twgl.setUniforms(mipProgramInfo, uniforms);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mipmap level also depends on the size of the texture. The mipmap level is a measure of how many (square)texels should be squeezed into one fragment. In the answer to the linked question ([How to access automatic mipmap level in GLSL fragment shader texture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388346/how-to-access-automatic-mipmap-level-in-glsl-fragment-shader-texture)), the mipmap level is calculated from the texture coordinate multiplied by the size of the texture:

> ```c
> mip_map_level(textureCoord * textureSize(myTexture, 0));
> ```

You missed that part in your code. So the formula should be:

```c
vec2 size = vec2(128.0, 128.0); // size of the texture in your example
vec2 dx = dFdx(v_texCoord * size);
vec2 dy = dFdy(v_texCoord * size);
float deltaMaxSq = max(dot(dx, dx), dot(dy, dy));
float mipLevel = 0.5 * log2(deltaMaxSq);
```

Also, you need to round the mipmap level when you look up the color:

<s>`outColor = colors[int(mipLevel)];`</s>

```c
outColor = colors[int(mipLevel + 0.5)];
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  height: 100%;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>

<script type="module">
import * as twgl from 'https://twgljs.org/dist/5.x/twgl-full.module.js';

const vs = `#version 300 es
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
uniform mat3 u_texMat;

out vec2 v_texCoord;

const vec2 position[6] = vec2[6](
  vec2(0, 0),
  vec2(1, 0),
  vec2(0, 1),
  vec2(0, 1),
  vec2(1, 0),
  vec2(1, 1));

void main() {
  vec2 p = position[gl_VertexID];
  v_texCoord = (u_texMat * vec3(p, 1)).xy;
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * vec4(p, 0, 1);
}
`;
const fsTex = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;

in vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_tex;

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  outColor = texture(u_tex, v_texCoord);
}
`;
const fsMipLevel = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;

in vec2 v_texCoord;

out vec4 outColor;

const vec4 colors[8] = vec4[8](
  vec4(  1,   0,   0, 1), // 0: red
  vec4(  1,   1,   0, 1), // 1: yellow
  vec4(  0,   1,   0, 1), // 2: green
  vec4(  0,   1,   1, 1), // 3: cyan
  vec4(  0,   0,   1, 1), // 4: blue
  vec4(  1,   0,   1, 1), // 5: magenta
  vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1), // 6: gray
  vec4(  1,   1,   1, 1));// 7: white

void main() {
  vec2 size = vec2(128.0, 128.0); // size of the texture in your example
  vec2 dx = dFdx(v_texCoord * size);
  vec2 dy = dFdy(v_texCoord * size);
  float deltaMaxSq = max(dot(dx, dx), dot(dy, dy));
  float mipLevel = 0.5 * log2(deltaMaxSq);
  
  // mipLevel = mod(gl_FragCoord.x / 16.0, 8.0);  // comment in to test we can use the colors

  outColor = colors[int(mipLevel + 0.5)];

  // outColor = vec4(mipLevel / 7.0, 0, 0, 1);  // comment in to visualize another way
  // outColor = vec4(fract(v_texCoord), 0, 1);  // comment in to visualize texcoord
}
`;

const colors = [
  '#F00',
  '#FF0',
  '#0F0',
  '#0FF',
  '#00F',
  '#F0F',
  '#888',
  '#FFF',
];


function createMips(colors) {
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  const numMips = colors.length;
  return colors.map((color, i) => {
    const size = 2 ** (numMips - i - 1);
    ctx.canvas.width = size;
    ctx.canvas.height = size;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, size, size);
  });
}

function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl2");
  if (!gl) {
    alert("Sorry, this example requires WebGL 2.0");  // eslint-disable-line
    return;
  }

  const texProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fsTex]);
  const mipProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fsMipLevel]);

  const texImage = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texImage);
  const data = createMips(colors);
  data.forEach(({width, height, data}, level) => {
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, gl.RGBA8, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
  });
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

  const lerp = (a, b, t) => a + (b - a) * t;

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;
    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    const uniforms = {};

    const s = lerp(1, 128, Math.sin(time) * 0.5 + 0.5);
    uniforms.u_texMat = [
      s, 0, 0,
      0, s, 0,
      0, 0, 1,
    ];
    uniforms.u_worldViewProjection = m4.translation([-1.01, -0.5, 0]);

    gl.useProgram(texProgramInfo.program);
    twgl.setUniforms(texProgramInfo, uniforms);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    uniforms.u_worldViewProjection = m4.translation([0.01, -0.5, 0]);

    gl.useProgram(mipProgramInfo.program);
    twgl.setUniforms(mipProgramInfo, uniforms);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```